# xrandr missing hdmi output after install nvidia driver

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, hdmi

Hi i have notebook where are intel and nvidia graphic cards.

- Intel 630HD
- Nvidia 1060, driver 410.78
- Ubuntu 18.04

After fresh install nvidia works fine. I don't know exactly what happend (maybe any system updates). Nvidia does not see **HDMI output** if i uninstall nvidia, i run on nouveau and use `xrandr` **HDMI output** is detected. And external monitor works fine, but nouveau does not support audio by HDMI. And nvidia does not see HDMI.

What is need for move forward? Log?

Could you help me?

**EDIT:**
Here is answer from [nvidia forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1044770/linux/hdmi-output-missing-in-xrandr-command-and-external-monitor-not-work/#comment_5301177)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for posting the link to the answer! This also fixed the problem for me.

The Nvidia forum lists more steps. But the following worked for me:

1. edit the file `/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-kms.conf`. Change the line `options nvidia-drm modeset=1` to `options nvidia-drm modeset=0`.
2. Run `sudo update-initramfs -u`.
3. Then just reboot your computer.

After this, my HDMI output worked perfectly.

It is also worth noting that the HDMI port is not detected when I am using the "Intel (Power Saving Mode)" PRIME profile. However, the HDMI port works fine again when I switch to the "NVIDIA (Performance Mode)" profile.

Comment: What to do to use HDMI in intel mode? I have exactly the same issue. :(

Comment: I don’t think it’s possible. You have to be in NVIDIA mode.

Comment: That's the answer! <3